# Trigger on parent property changed, but Set property for a child of a specific type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I don't know if this is possible and i don't know much about wpf.

I have this TabControl with 2 TabItems each contain a TextBox

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabStyle}" Header="TabItem1">
            <TextBox/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabStyle}" Header="TabItem2">
            <TextBox/>
        </TabItem>
 </TabControl>
```

and I have this style for the TabItem

```
<Style x:Key="TabStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="tab is focused"/> <!--Point this setter to the textbox inside the tab item -->
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="false">
                   <Setter Property="Text" Value="tab is focused"/><!--Point this setter to the textbox inside the tab item -->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

if my tab item has only one control of type TextBox, is it possible to modify that text box from the setter inside of the tab item trigger, how can I find the child of type TextBox without using names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest binding the TabItem's IsFocused property to a bool property in your ViewModel. I'd also bind the TextBox Text property to a string in the ViewModel.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem IsFocused="{Binding IsFocused}" Header="TabItem1">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding IsFocusedText}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

You can then create a method to change the TextBox value whenever the TabItem IsFocused like so:

```
public bool _isFocused;
public bool IsFocused
{
   get { return _isFocused; }
   set
   {
      if (value == _isFocused)
         return;
      _isFocused = value;
      OnIsFocusedChanged(value);
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsFocused);
}

private void OnIsFocusedChanged(bool isFocused)
{
   if (isFocused)
      IsFocusedText = "tab is focused";
   else
      IsFocusedText = "tab is NOT focused";
}

public bool _isFocusedText;
public bool IsFocusedText
{
   get { return _isFocusedText; }
   set
   {
      if (value == _isFocusedText)
         return;
      _isFocusedText = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsFocusedText);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another option:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Name="TabItem1" Header="TabItem1">
        <TextBox Text="tab is NOT focused" >
           <TextBox.Style>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=TabItem1}" Value=True>
                       <Setter Property="Text" Value="tab is focused" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
           </TextBox.Style>
         </TextBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Lee thats exactly what i did, so its not possible with XAML only?

Comment: Well...you could put the trigger in a style on the TextBox. Then bind the trigger property to the TabItem. I'll edit with an example of that.

Comment: i would appreciate that!

Comment: If you want to make this reusable on other tabs, use AncestorType instead of ElementName to "lookup" the TabItem.